# Draw shadow in a UITableViewCell cause visual error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm a beginner in swift. I want to draw a shadow behind my View in a `UITableViewCell` but when I add the following code :

```
func doTheWork(statutOfCard : statut){
    switch statutOfCard {
    case .selectPicture:
        cardViewHeightCon.constant = 300
        if ShadowLayerCard == nil{
            self.addCardShadow()
        }
    case .modifyPicture:
        cardViewHeightCon.constant = 400
        if ShadowLayerCard == nil{
            self.addCardShadow()
        }
    default:
        cardViewHeightCon.constant = 300
        if ShadowLayerCard == nil{
            self.addCardShadow()
        }
    }
}

func addCardShadow(){
    let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    ShadowLayerCard = shadowLayer
    shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(0, 0, widthOfDevice! - (widthMarginConstraint*2), cardViewHeightCon.constant), cornerRadius: 10).cgPath
    shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x00ff33).cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    cardView.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
}
```

the shadow appears in the `UITableViewCell` but when I scroll down, this produces a visual bug like this:

[image]

I think that the shadow is drawn before the height of the `cardView` was updated, but how can I fix this problem? And if I need to add another component like a picture programmatically, can I write this in the `doTheWork` function? Or will this produce a bug again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add shadow to `cardView.layer` and do it once when the cell created. You might need another view to hold your image with rounded corners, because you will need to set clip to bound true for corners.

```
func addCardShadow(){
    let shadowLayer = cardView.layer
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 5
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
}
```